# Azure devops pipeline - PythonScript@0 task - pass json as argument

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a PythonScript@0 azure devops pipeline task below:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: '$(workingDir)/test.py'
    arguments: '{"arg1": "value1", "arg2": "value2"}'
```

In my test.py file, my code is:

```
  test = sys.argv[1]
  print(test)
```

When I run this I get:
**{arg1:**

My end goal is to pass in a json 'string' as an argument in this python task, and then use json.loads() to load in the argument as json. No matter what i do I can't seem to get this to work? Any thoughts as to how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by just calling it through a script task rather than the python task, eg:

```
- script: "python -u $(workingDir)/test.py '$(request)'"
  displayName: 'Run script.py'
```

Where $(request) is a variable that contains a string like {"arg1": "value1", "arg2": "value2"}

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the way this task works, the problem is just that your arguments need to quote your argument. This may be confusing because your single quotes are not *actually* in your argument, they're being processed as part of the YAML file!

So, what you have right now will be the same as if you did the following on the command line, which will give the effect you're observing:

```bash
python ./path/to/test.py {"arg1": "value1", "arg2": "value2"}
```

To fix this, change your YAML as follows to include the single quotes around your argument (in YAML, two single quotes (`''`) within a single-quoted YAML scalar evaluates to a single literal quote `'`):

```yaml
    arguments: '''{"arg1": "value1", "arg2": "value2"}'''
```

This should give the effect as if passed on the command line as a single argument how you want:

```bash
python ./path/to/test.py '{"arg1": "value1", "arg2": "value2"}'
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work, I get the error:
error: unrecognized arguments: value1, arg2: value2}'